# Proper Way To Import And Manipulate Objects In Multiprocessing Pool?

Tags: python, object, multiprocessing

I have a very simple multiprocessing script that I can't get to work.

What I need it to do is:

- Process and iterate through item_list
- Run a counter for each item processed
- Print an item from msg_list based on the counter

The processes are conflicting with each other. I tried many things like using lock(), and passing everything through map but I couldn't get it working.

Here's the code

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock

counter = 0
msg_list = ["message1", "message2", "message3", "message4", "message5", "message6", "message7", "message8", "message9", "message10", "message11", "message12"]


def increment(item):

    global counter
    global msg_list

    print(counter, item, msg_list[counter])
    counter = counter + 1


if __name__ == '__main__':

    item_list = ["item1",
                 "item2",
                 "item3",
                 "item4",
                 "item5",
                 "item6",
                 "item7",
                 "item8",
                 "item9",
                 "item10",
                 "item11",
                 "item12"]

    p = Pool(4)
    p.map(increment, item_list)
    p.terminate()
```

How the output should look:

```
0 item1 message1
1 item2 message2
2 item3 message3
3 item4 message4
4 item5 message5
5 item6 message6
6 item7 message7
7 item8 message8
8 item9 message9
9 item10 message10
10 item11 message11
11 item12 message12
```

How the output currently looks

```
0 item1 message1
1 item2 message2
2 item3 message3
3 item4 message4
4 item6 message5
0 item5 message1
5 item7 message6
1 item8 message2
6 item9 message7
7 item10 message8
2 item11 message3
8 item12 message9
```

Comment: Are you running on windows or a unixlike system? Things like `counter` are unique per subprocess so you wouldin't expect an increment in one to affect the other. Is it important that `counter` work across processes, because that level of synchronization can really slow things down.

Comment: Can you add a short description of what you want to happen? If you just want to associate item1 with message1, etc, you could pass them to the worker together. If this is a linux-like forking system, you could pass counter as a parameter because the child has a copy-on-write view of the parent memory space.

Comment: As @tdelaney points it out, you are laboring under the misapprehension of global variables being shared between processes.

They are *copied* from your main process with the value the have at the time the "sub" process is started.

Thus it is always 0 first, in all 4 subprocesses from the pool. Then when the function is called on each item from the "chunk" if items allotted to the process, counter increments but only in that process.

Comment: @tdelaney - I'm running a windows system. Picture the code I shared if the 'items' were a list of URLs to iterate through. I use requests and BS4 in the function, and the 'message' is scraped data like for example, a server status (which I need to save to pandas dataframe in the correct cell). It's kind of complicated so I tried to make a barebones example as seen above. I need synchronization, speed isn't a concern.

Comment: @petre - ya you're absolutely right about that. what would you suggest to get the script working? can I somehow push it all through map? can I get the processes to iterate through "counter", "msg_list", "item_list" all at once so I can access them all in the function?

Comment: Yes, you can use e.g. shared memory (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) but I would not recommend that, generally. Rather, you might want to prepare the workload in the main process, or use queues. It really depends on what you really want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, processes do not share any process space unless you setup shared memory. And shared memory is awkward with python because any shared data still needs to be wrapped in python objects.

When the pool is created, worker processes start a new instance of python and then the state of the parent process is pickled, sent to the worker and unpickled. This can be an expensive operation. The goal generally is to keep the interprocess communication low compared to the cpu work being done.

From your notes I take it that `msg_list` is really stuff scraped from a web page. This is good! Here is a general outline to push the scraping into a worker process:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # imports not needed in worker
    import pandas as pd

def worker(url):
    import requests
    try:
        data = requests.get(url)
        interesting = do_your_scraping()
        return = format_for_pandas(interesting)
    except AnyExceptionsYouShouldCatch:
        return default_payload # whatever you want an error
                               # to look like
def main():
    import pandas
    with open("file_with_urls.txt") as urls_file:
        urls = [line.strip() for line in urls_file]
    with mp.Pool(4) as pool:
        df = pd.DataFrame(pool.map(worker, urls, chunksize=1)
```

Since much of the time is spent waiting for the remote web server to respond, if you really do need communication among the workers, consider a thread pool instead. Only one thread can run at a time, but if most are blocked waiting for the remote, then it still runs well.

Also consider that there are web scraping tools out there like `scrappy`. You may find it suites your needs.